# SVGs only rendering in mobile safari with private browsing

Tags: jquery, html, svg, mobile, safari

I have a desktop website using SVGs that show correctly. On mobile, the images are not rendering properly in normal Safari browsing mode, but they do render properly when in *private* browsing.

What is it about regular browsing that leads to them not rendering correctly?

**CORRECT RENDERING: PRIVATE BROWSING ON SAFARI:**

[image]

**INCORRECT RENDERING: REGULAR BROWSING ON SAFARI**

[image]

Comment: Could it have something to do with browser caching? If you used the browser to test before with different versions of the assets or CSS that could be it. Have you tried in other devices?

Comment: @mathielo - silly me, that was it! If you write as an answer I will select as correct. Many thanks.

Comment: Aha cool! Glad I could be of help. Posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could possibly be a simple issue with browser testing. New changes to existing assets without renaming (e.g. change the SVG's XML or update an image) could be hindered by browser caching. Even some CSS changes are tricky to bypass caching sometimes.

Try testing in other devices in the "same browser" (Safari) and you know if it's a caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have an adblocker or similar extension installed on your test IOS device ?
They might interfer with the loading of your SVG if they contain "ad" in the name or path.
And they aren't usually loaded in "Private mode"